# No file was submitted error when uploading data to Django REST API

Tags: python, django, typescript, django-rest-framework

Im using angular/typescript where I upload a form of data to my Django REST API. With the data all is correct, because I can log my whole form and I get back all my data. But when it comes to upload the data I get this error:

> `{src: ["No file was submitted."], tag: ["This field is required."]}`

so somehow it does not recognize my data because Im actually submitting data.

frontend code

upload.service

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
};

...

  uploadPost(src: File, tag: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`{this.url}/posts/`, {src, tag}, httpOptions);
}
```

post.page

```
  ngOnInit() {

  this.storage.get('image_data').then((imageFile) => {
      console.log(imageFile)
      this.categoryForm.patchValue({
        'image': this.storage.get('image_data')
      });
    });

        this.categoryForm = new FormGroup({

          'category': new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
            Validators.maxLength(25),
            Validators.minLength(1),
            Validators.required
          ])),

          'image': new FormControl(null),
        });

apiSubmit() {
console.log('logged')
console.log(this.f.image);
this.submitted = true;
if (this.categoryForm.invalid) {
  return;
}
this.isLoading = true;
this.loadingEl.present();
this.uploadService.uploadPost(
  this.f.image,
  this.f.category
    )
.pipe(tap(x => this.loadingEl.dismiss())
)
.subscribe(
  data => {
    this.router.navigate(['one']);
  },
  error => {
    this.error = error;
  }
);
}
```

Django:

models.py

```
   class Post(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        src = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False, editable=False, upload_to=utils.get_file_path,)
        date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
        last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        when = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        lock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        des = models.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            validators=[
                RegexValidator(
                    regex='^[-_a-zA-Z0-9\.]+$',
                    message='only 1 to 20 characters and only letters, numbers, point, minus and underscore are allowed',
                ),
            ])
```

view.py

```
      @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=doc_serializer.CreatePostDummy, responses={201: PostSerializer})
            def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                """permission required: authenticated. Note: the schema is not json it's multipart"""
                return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

doc_serializers.py

```
    class CreatePostDummy(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        `enter code here`user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(required=False, read_only=True, view_name='user-detail')
        src = serializers.CharField(required=True, help_text='Not Char but image upload field')
```

Comment: Are you actually submitting data? Look in your browser debugger, Network tab, to see the exact request you're sending.

Comment: `{src: {__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value: {}}, tag: "gh89"}
src: {__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value: {}}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: {}
tag: "gh89"`this is my request payload

Comment: I don't get why my file value is empty there when I log this.f.image I get the full value...